# Restricting auto generation of schemas definitions OpenAPI Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

When running the Spring Boot application with `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.7.0` when using nested complex types as properties, the generated schemas represent separate types as well as whole classes, for example:

```
@RestController
class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    fun getA(): A {
        return A(A.B(name = "Tom"))
    }
}

data class A(val b: B) {
    data class B(val name: String)
}
```

will result in generating in OpenAPI definition:

- the schema for class B
- the schema for class A consisting class B

I wonder if there is any way in Spring Boot either on the configuration level through properties file or specific bean registration to restrict it to only having high-level schemas generated?